# Submeter formulário no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Estou tentando submeter um formulário no site https://www.loskatchorros.com.br/ucp/login.php ,porém já procurei diversas maneiras aqui no *stackoverflow* de como submeter um formulário, e nao achei nenhuma maneira que solucionasse este problema.

**Este é um exemplo de código que peguei aqui no fórum e não funcionou.**

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'login':'*******','senha':'******'}

session = requests.Session()
r = session.post('https://www.loskatchorros.com.br/ucp/login.php',headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Ao colocar a linha:

```
print (r.text)
```

O programa retorna o mesmo código-fonte da página https://www.loskatchorros.com.br/ucp/login.php, isso da a entender que o formulário não foi submetido com exito, e queria saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Se precisarem do login e senha verdadeiros peçam que eu mando sem nenhum problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

account = {'login': 'muze@balanc3r.com', 'senha': 'muze123'}
abs_domain = 'https://www.loskatchorros.com.br/' #1
form = 'ucp/global/verifica_login.php' #2
absolute_form_URL = abs_domain + form 

requests_session = requests.Session() #3
r = requests_session.post(url=absolute_form_URL, data=account) #4

text = r.text[-79:] if r.status_code == 200 else None #5
print('Status code [%s].' % r.status_code, text, sep='\n')
```

- #1 Domínio absoluto
- #2 Caminho para o form de autenticação
- #3 "Instância a sessão"
- #4 Faz o método POST com o objeto session
- #5 Obtém uma fatia do texto recebido caso a autenticação seja bem sucessida

`>>> Status code [200].`
`>>> Usuário ou senha incorretos, verifique e tente novamente!</div></body>
</html>`

Comment: Você fornecendo suas credencias aqui, é muito provável que apaguem sua conta. Tente utilizar Selenium nesses casos de redirecionamento. Me parece que ele está tentando abrir uma janela com cloudfire.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que enviar o post com os dados a página de destino do formulário, não para  a página que gera o formuláriom em HTML.

A URL para essa página é a que está no campo "action" da tag `form`. Nesse caso, `global/verifica_login.php` (e não `login.php`).

Em frameworks modernos web em geral a URL que gera o html de um formulário e o que processa o formulário é o mesmo - e isso facilita a criação da interface de validação de dados. Mas o autor de um site pode por os endereços que quiser, e se for um sistema feito a mão, sem estar aproveitando código de um framework, é mais simples ter páginas separadas.